# Bootstrapped Correlation for Nested data using Tidymodels

Tags: r, tidyverse, bootstrapping, tidymodels

I have a **monthly (Jan - Dec)** data set for weather and crop yield. This data is collected for multiple **years (2002 - 2019)**. My aim is to obtain bootstrapped correlation coefficient of the relationship between temperature in each month and yield gap.

Here is the data and code.

```r
# Load libraries
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(reprex)

# data 
ww_wt <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MohsinRamay/yieldgap/main/ww_wt.csv")
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> Rows: 1924 Columns: 20
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr   (3): ID, Location, Month
#> dbl  (16): ...1, Year, Latitude, Longitude, YieldTrt, YieldUntrt, Mildew, Ye...
#> date  (1): Date
#> 
#> i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

ww_wt %>% 
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    Year Month       gap  temp
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2002 September 0.282 13.6 
#> 2  2002 October   0.282 13.3 
#> 3  2002 November  0.282  7.07
#> 4  2002 December  0.282  3.44
#> 5  2002 January   0.282  5.61
#> 6  2002 February  0.282  6.93

# Bootstrapping
set.seed(123)

ww_wt %>% 
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  nest(data = -c(Month)) %>%
  mutate(boots = map(data, ~bootstraps(.x, times = 100, apparent = FALSE))) %>%
  unnest(boots) %>% 
  mutate(correlations = map(splits, ~cor.test(.x$gap, .x$temp), tidied = map(correlations, tidy)))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `correlations`.
#> i `correlations = map(...)`.
#> x 'x' must be a numeric vector
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This code is perfectly working for regression analysis, however, when I tweak it for correlation it is giving this error. Can somebody look what's going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. Instead of using `cor.test` from `stats` package, I have used `core_test` from `rstatix` package and it is working perfectly fine.

Here is the updated code:

```r
# Load libraries
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(reprex)
library(rstatix)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rstatix'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:infer':
#> 
#>     chisq_test, prop_test, t_test
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dials':
#> 
#>     get_n
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter

# data 
ww_wt <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MohsinRamay/yieldgap/main/ww_wt.csv")
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> Rows: 1924 Columns: 20
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr   (3): ID, Location, Month
#> dbl  (16): ...1, Year, Latitude, Longitude, YieldTrt, YieldUntrt, Mildew, Ye...
#> date  (1): Date
#> 
#> i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

ww_wt %>% 
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    Year Month       gap  temp
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2002 September 0.282 13.6 
#> 2  2002 October   0.282 13.3 
#> 3  2002 November  0.282  7.07
#> 4  2002 December  0.282  3.44
#> 5  2002 January   0.282  5.61
#> 6  2002 February  0.282  6.93

# Bootstrapping
set.seed(123)

ww_wt %>% 
  nest(data = -c(Month)) %>% 
  mutate(boots = map(data, ~bootstraps(.x, times = 100, apparent = FALSE))) %>%
  unnest(boots) %>%
  mutate(correlations = map(splits, ~cor_test(gap, temp, data = analysis((.)))))
#> # A tibble: 1,200 x 5
#>    Month     data                splits           id           correlations     
#>    <chr>     <list>              <list>           <chr>        <list>           
#>  1 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/61]> Bootstrap001 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  2 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/59]> Bootstrap002 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  3 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/56]> Bootstrap003 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  4 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/61]> Bootstrap004 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  5 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/57]> Bootstrap005 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  6 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/56]> Bootstrap006 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  7 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/60]> Bootstrap007 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  8 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/56]> Bootstrap008 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#>  9 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/64]> Bootstrap009 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#> 10 September <tibble [161 x 19]> <split [161/58]> Bootstrap010 <cor_test [1 x 8~
#> # ... with 1,190 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>